# How to customize TTMessageController fields?

Tags: iphone, xcode, three20

I use the [TTMessageController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php) to get an recipient picker and a text area for writing sms messages. However there is still this "subject" field that I do not need.

How do I remove it?

This is how I create [TTMessageController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php):

```
self.second [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.second release];

UINavigationViewController *navigationController = 
              [[UINavigationController alloc]
               initWithRootViewController:self.second];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

SecondViewController is a subclass of [TTMessageController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php). So how do I customize it to remove/add fields, especially the subject field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of TTMessageController and override the initWithNibName. In your overidden initWithNibName method set the _fields array to keep just the fields you want to have. The example below will keep only the To: field.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {

        self.dataSource = [[AddressBookDataSource new] autorelease];


        _fields = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                   [[[TTMessageRecipientField alloc] initWithTitle: TTLocalizedString(@"To:", @"")
                                                           required: YES] autorelease], nil];



        self.showsRecipientPicker = YES;

        self.title = TTLocalizedString(@"New Message", @"");

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                  initWithTitle: TTLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"")
                                                  style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                  target: self
                                                  action: @selector(cancel)] autorelease];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: what is SMSMessageRecipientField? Do I have to create it?

Comment: Sorry, that's a subclass of TTMessageRecipientField in my project. You can replace with TTMessageRecipientField.